# Функция не возвращает значение(не производит вычисления)

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть код разделяющий фотографию на заданное число квадратов, и мне нужно, чтобы он возвращал массив этих элементов(каждого квадратика), но он возвращает пустой массив.

Но если в функции внутри цикла выводить каждый элемент в консоль всё работает нормально.

```js
var img = new Image();
var width;
var height;
var xlength = 30;
var ylength = 20;
var elements = []; //массив-------------------------------------------------------

img.src = 'http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg';

img.onload = function() {
  width = this.width;
  height = this.height;
  for (var j = 0; j < ylength; j++) {

    for (var i = 0; i < xlength; i++) {

      var left = (-1 * width / xlength * i).toString() + "px";
      var top = (-1 * height / ylength * j).toString() + "px";

      var element = jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: i + "" + j,
        class: "splitImg",
        css: {
          "width": Math.floor(width / xlength),
          "height": Math.floor(height / ylength),
          "background-position": left + " " + top,
          "background-image": 'url(' + img.src + ')'
        }
      })
      elements += element[0]; //добавление элементов------------------------------
      element.appendTo('#wrapper');
      $("#wrapper").width(width + (xlength * -0.5))
    }
  }
}

console.log(elements);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.splitImg {
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы вызываете `console.log(elements);`, не дожидаясь пока отработает событие `onload`. Естественно в массиве еще ничего нет.

И что должна делать строчка `elements += element[0];`, складывающая массив с DOM-элементом? Может `elements.push(element[0]);`?

---

> как сделать чтобы массив заполнялся этими объектами

Пора сказать слово "асинхронность".

Массив заполняется этими объектами - внутри обработчика `onload`. Вы можете в этом убедиться, если дождетесь загрузки изображения с сервера на клиент и выведете

```
console.log(elements);
```

в конце этой анонимной функции.

Обратите внимание на ссылку в комментарии под вопросом:

[Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6)

Comment: elements.push(element[0]) помог, он создаёт массив, но когда я пытаюсь получить доступ к элементу этого массива например: console.log(elements[0]), он выводит в консоль 'undefined'. Как сделать чтобы он выводил элемент с заданным индексом?

Comment: @Александр Сконцентрируйтесь на первом абзаце моего ответа. Вам понятно, о чем в нем говорится?

Comment: А как сделать чтобы массив заполнялся этими объектами?